# Disable Oracle recycle bin for specific users

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, flashback

To keep aligned with organizational policies and developmental framework and also keep the Database storage & space management clean, I want to disable Oracle Recycle Bin for non-DBA users.

Is there a way to disable recycle bin for specific users, or does it have to be global enabled/disabled/?

Comment: Have you tried an `AFTER LOGON` trigger to `ALTER SESSION SET RECYCLEBIN OFF` for those users?

Comment: @Matthew McPeak the clever user will simply run `ALTER SESSION SET RECYCLEBIN ON` to bypass this protection.

Comment: @krokodilko True, but it is better than nothing.  My understanding was that the OP's goal is a policy matter, not a security matter.  An `AFTER LOGON` trigger will make the system enforce the policy by default, so that violations only occur due to willful action (such as you have described), which can be audited and disciplined as needed.